# I don't understand how the sign of argument works in a function with arguments that could be positive, negative or in between

Tags: functions, asymptotics

this formula is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function
i want to know what is the value of Ai(large negative number) but if z is negative the formula below gives minusxminus = positive argument!  what is going on?

gives $$ Ai(-z) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} \sin({\frac{2}{3}z^{\frac {3}{2}} +\pi/4)} $$

Could someone explain the convention on interpreting the minus sign in the argument?
Is that understood to be minus one times  the absolute value of z?  If that is the case then it make since but why wouldn't they put the absolute value in?  I am really confused about functions whose arguments are complex numbers, do we always assume it is the absolute value or do we just do this for asymptotic stuff?

Comment: What does " z -> large and too to the left " mean??

Comment: i want to know what is the value of Ai(large negative number)

Comment: But $\,z\in\Bbb C\,$ , right? So what does being large in the complex field mean? Do you mean its module?

Comment: large modulus but with phase pi, that is what a negative number is right

Comment: Can't you just define $x=-z$  and replace all instances of z in the original function definition?